# How do you set jade basedir option in an express app? (the "basedir" option is required to use "extends" with "absolute" paths)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Going through the peepcode nodejs video and recreating the app on the current express/node versions I've ran into a small issue.

file structure

```
site
 - apps
 - - authentication
 - - - views
 - - - - login.jade
 - - - routes.js
 - node_modules
 - public
 - - images
 - - javascripts
 - - stylesheets
 - routes
 - views
 app.js
```

login.jade:

```
extends /views/layout
block content
  form(action='/sessions', method='post')
    label
      | Username
      input(type='text', name='user')
    label
      | Password
      input(type='password', name='password')
    input(type='submit', name='submit')
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', { basedir: process.env.__dirname})
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

require('./apps/authentication/routes')(app)

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

When I navigate to `localhost:3000/login` I receive the following error:

```
Error: /Users/bob/code/site/apps/authentication/views/login.jade:1 
  > 1| extends /views/layout 
    2| block content
    3| form(action='/sessions', method='post')
    4| label

the "basedir" option is required to use "extends" with "absolute" paths
```

I can update the extends line to: extends ../../../views/layout and make it work, but I'd prefer to know how to set the basedir option.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use this:

```
app.locals.basedir = '/your/base/directory';
```

Or, using the newer Express method,

```
app.locals.basedir = path.join(__dirname, 'views');
```

Comment: Strange, that solved the problem for me (jade@0.30.0, express@3.2.4). Another way it should work is to pass `basedir` as a parameter with `render`: `res.render('templatename', { basedir : '/your/base/directory', ... })`. Also works for me ([gist of minimal demo](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5570115)).

Comment: Nevermind works fine. I was making a dumb assumption that process.env.__dirname was current root directory in app start for some reason.  I'm now using app.locals.basedir = process.env.PWD and that works great.  Thank you!

Comment: @jackyalcine see the gist I referred to (here it is again: [link](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5570115))

Comment: why isn't this set by default?

Answer (score 11):

In express, you'll notice that there is,

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

You can just put this line in then,

```
app.locals.basedir = app.get('views');
```

Which makes the basedir available to `jade.js` so it can resolve absolute paths.

Comment: Any way to do this without using `locals`?