# using common layout for all the pages in pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying out pug with express

```
views/layout.pug 

doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel="shortcut icon", href="favicon.ico", type="image/x-icon")
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/assets/application.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
  body    
    script(src="assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")
    script(src='assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    script(src="assets/application.js")
    block content
```

This is the router for User page.

```
routes/user.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('user/index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have my view for user/index page. I extends the layout from the views. User index page using the layout. layout.pug is present in views folder.

If  I add a layout.pug inside views/user it works. But how to use the views/layout.pug

```
/views/user/index.pug

extends layout


block content
    h1
     | User index
```

i get the following error. it is looking for layout in view/user folder. How to make it to use view/layout.pug.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\my_projects\myexpressapp\views\user\layout.pug'
    at C:\my_projects\myexpressapp\views\user\index.pug line 1
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
    at Function.read (C:\my_projects\myexpressapp\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:69:13)
    at Object.read (C:\my_projects\myexpressapp\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:147:25)
    at C:\my_projects\myexpressapp\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:24:25
    at walkAST (C:\my_projects\myexpressapp\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:23:18)
    at C:\my_projects\myexpressapp\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:104:20
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at walkAndMergeNodes (C:\my_projects\myexpressapp\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:103:18)
```

Comment: As the error says, the file layout.pug is not in proper import location

Comment: if add a layout.pug inside views/user it works. But how to use the views/layout.pug

Comment: try `extends ../layout`

Comment: thank you very much it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.js` file, check whether you have defined the views properly.

View engine should be set to pug and views folder should be set properly as described below in `app.js`

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the `baseDirectory` variable.

I'm not familiar with Express, I found the answer [How do you set jade basedir option in an express app? (the "basedir" option is required to use "extends" with "absolute" paths)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525362/how-do-you-set-jade-basedir-option-in-an-express-app-the-basedir-option-is-r)

Comment: app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

I have in my server.js.

Comment: Did you try this `app.locals.basedir = app.get('views');` ? Once you set the variable, you can use `extends /layout` *the pas must be starts with "/"*.